# Tell TeXstudio to compile a particular document with LuaLaTeX

Tags: compiling, texstudio, magic-comment

It is not hard to change the default compilation engine in TeXstudio from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX (or any other engine for that matter). But if I only want to use LuaLaTeX for a single document, it gets tedious to go into the menus and find the LuaLaTeX option all the time. And the command line approach is also more time-consuming.

**Is there some clever way to tell TeXstudio to always compile *this* (and only *this*) document using LuaLaTeX?**

Comment: you can define a shortcut for example (F10 if you don't use glossary)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Just insert the “magic comment”

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
```

at the beginning of your `.tex` file.

Comment: And this works regardless of what editor I use?

Comment: It may work with some other editors, but not all. It doesn't work for my own preferred editor, for example: TeXShop (on Mac OS X). The magic comment for TeXShop would have been `% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX`

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment, the magic command syntax for TeXStudio seems to work also for TeXworks: http://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/. I've just tried it with TeXmaker, unsuccessffuly.

Comment: @fpast TeXmaker doesn't appear to support the directives, see our [LaTeX IDE list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402).

Comment: For more details what can configure with "magic comments" in TeXstudio see the manual: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION_TEXCOM

Comment: @FranckPastor, why does it not work if I replace the line by `% !TeX program = context`?

Comment: @Gaussler Maybe Context is not yet taken into account by TeXStudio. It was not recognized by TeXStudio last year, by the way. See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/87628

Answer (score 0):

- You click on options
- You go got "Build" side tab
- And change "Default Compiler" to LuaLaTeX